# Generate EXE from Flex Project Using mxmlc

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, mxml, projector

How to generate an Executable file of my MXML (flex) Application. 
What is the command using in command prompt for MXMLC.exe.

Comment: Do you want an exe that will be an installer for the application?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to generate a SWF file as usual. The Open your compiled SWF in Flash Player and select **File** -> **Create Projector...**

[image]